# Convert date column to yyyy-mm in CSV python

Tags: python, csv

how can I convert the `'month_date_yyyymm'` to date format, such as yyyy/mm. So that I can filter it.

I use pandas `read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

now. the column is opened like this:

```
month_date_yyyymm

202101 
202102 
202103
```

....

[image]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
In particular, we expect you to look up how to work with date formats before you post here.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

use pd.to_datetime and specify format as format='%Y%m'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month_date_yyyymm': [202101, 202102, 202103]})

df.month_date_yyyymm = pd.to_datetime(df.month_date_yyyymm, format='%Y%m')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

it wil convert from `Name: month_date_yyyymm, dtype: int64`

to `Name: month_date_yyyymm, dtype: datetime64[ns]`